# How to make a shadow under a button that goes over other buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, button, widget

What I'm trying to do is to make a button cast a shadow over other buttons in a relativelayout; What I currently have is this:

[current http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42852467/device-2012-05-04-205730.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42852467/device-2012-05-04-205730.png)

What I need is this, however:

[need http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42852467/UI%20Design.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42852467/UI%20Design.png)

I tried using the View on top of a View method, but it does not quite work in a relativelayout to cover other buttons. the shadow attribute only casts a shadow under the text, so that does not work either. My idea was to use a 9-patch and make the button oversized in an absolutelayout, but tiling the lined pattern would not work correctly then. Any ideas?

Also if anybody could tell me how to use a custom ttf font in an android app, that would be splendid.

Answer (score 0):

Try follow instruction:

To do so you have to make the image of the button with shadow and place on the button as drawable.

You can create custom Button like different image for different action like pressed,focused,enable and disable.

below tutorial make custom button try this link

http://www.thesecretpie.com/2010/07/creating-custom-fancy-buttons-in.html

Thanks...!

Comment: However, I want the button's shadow to cover other buttons; with this the shadow can only extend to as far as the next button begins, which defeats the purpose.